# Why is my hotplugging HID device app getting increasingly slower with each connection?

Tags: c++, qt, device, handle, hid

I'm using native windows code to enumerate over a list of HID devices and setup a connection based on hardware IDs. I'm doing this in a DLL which I'm using in a Qt app. I have no problem connecting, writing, and reading data. When I turn off the device I want my app to re-connect to the device automatically or another device that shares the same hardware IDs; however, on each subsequent connection it slows down the Qt GUI. For instance, shifting between tabs is noticeably delayed.

This led me to believe that maybe I'm not properly disconnecting from the HID device or there's a memory leak of some sort. If I restart the app, connect to the device again then the GUI runs normally.

Currently, while reading a report if there's a failure I'm triggering the "disconnect" process by closing the handles, but maybe this isn't enough? Is there a way I can "clean the slate" in a sense so I reconnect to the device without the data slowdown?

Here's my code where I close the I/O Handle and Event Handle:

```
char* HID::ReadReport() 
{
        DWORD BytesRead;
        InputReportBuffer[0] = REPORT_ID;
        BOOL Result = ReadFile(IOHandle, InputReportBuffer, Capabilities.InputReportByteLength, &BytesRead, (LPOVERLAPPED)&HIDOverlapped);
        if (Result)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    return InputReportBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Are these two handles the only resources you allocated when connecting?

Comment: Well, there’s hid capabilities and overlapped but I didn’t think those needed anything special.

Comment: @BenVoigt If there's an error while performing ReadFile is it enough just to close the handle?

Comment: Generally yes (at least it is with other USB device classes I use).  Do check for errors on the `CloseHandle()` call even though you can't do anything about them, because knowing when there is a problem is half the battle.

Comment: @BenVoigt I checked and both CloseHandle functions are successful.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm able to reconnect to my device in a different environment than Qt without a slowdown of the GUI. Same DLL so maybe it has something with the QLibrary which I'm using to load my DLL?

Comment: Are you using the Qt event handling system to process data from the device?  Are you subscribing listeners multiple times?

Comment: All the handling is done in my custom DLL using the Windows libraries and the setup a connection with "CreateFile" for my IOHandle. When there's a disconnect I trigger the connection function to look for the device handle again (since it's possible the Handle could have changed after disconnecting) or another device is able to connect. I successfully find the device handle again, send my initial messages successfully, and for all purposes the device connection is setup again except for the GUI slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Qt related. A QTimer connection setup related to the ReadReport function was being called multiple times leading to the slowdown on subsequent connection attempts.